# Display 25 images in viewpager cause outofmemoryerror for larger screen in android

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory

I am developing application where I am displaying animals images in landscape mode. I have to display it in around 70% of width of screen size. I have all 4 different sizes images in all 4 folders. So my hdpi folder contain image size is 480 x 420. And No image is more than 25Kb in this folder. And I have to display such around 25 - 30 images using viewpager. But It gives outofmemory error for larger screen. What is solution for that? All my images are local means I am not downloading any image from server. I have also used bitmapfactory method, but still it gives outofmemory error. Please give me solution.

Comment: Are you using FragmentStatePagerAdapter for you viewpager ?

Comment: Yes. I am using FragmentStatePagerAdapter.

Comment: You should recycle bitmap or null your view if not focused as like adapter does.